# Time complexity and number of operations

Tags: time-complexity

As defined (wiki)  time complexity of an algorithm quantifies the amount of time taken by an algorithm to run as a function of the length of the string representing the input.

Then how is that we count the number of elementary operations and call if time complexity ?
Doing so we are not even thinking of length of string representing the input ? Isn't it.

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: Let us say we have an array of size 'n'. We compute time complexity of any algorithm (per say - quicksort) as a function of n. But definition says time complexity is represented as a function of length of string representing the input. In this case length of string depends not just on length of array but also content of array. Isn't it ? Then how is that we represent complexity as a function of length of array.

Comment: In such case (if you have array of strings) and you are sorting them with the alphabetic order the time of comparing process is always less consuming than comparing 2 strings of maximum length and complexity of the algorithm is (n * log(n)) * time of single comparing(). So the only thing that changes is the (n) and as such it defines the complexity of he algorithm, the comparing process is also depending from input data but within one single task is constant.

Comment: Thank you! Can you please elaborate a bit on " (n * log(n)) * time of single comparing()"  Moreover last line is not clear to me as well ..

Comment: The complexity of the algorithm is basically "how many time consumable operation will we use to achieve our task". And this is the (n* log(n)) for the quick sort algorithm. Another thing is how much time this operation will cost. And this is the single comparison time. If you want to know more read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation or http://justin.abrah.ms/computer-science/big-o-notation-explained.html